# Complete newbie with Python but prepared to learn. Any help on using Beautiful Soup to source the 'Shot' data from this site much appreciated

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I can see the raw data in the div class="shots-wrapper" but the following code doesn't seem to access it?

```
import requests 
URL = "https://bet365.apps.imgarena.com/golf/3.18.0/full/?eventId=183&language=en&options=eyJ2aWRlb1BsYXliYWNrRW5hYmxlZCI6ZmFsc2V9#/group/30"
r = requests.get(URL) 
print(r.content)
```

Any pointers appreciated, as I say complete novice but willing to learn.

Thx

Comment: A professional title would attract more people to help you. Maybe adapt it. Also add the error message so that people can help you without executing the code themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can use selenium to do this.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://bet365.apps.imgarena.com/golf/3.18.0/full/?eventId=183&language=en&options=eyJ2aWRlb1BsYXliYWNrRW5hYmxlZCI6ZmFsc2V9#/group/30')

shotsbtn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div[3]')))

shotsbtn.click()

print(driver.page_source)
```

This will take u to the shots page. And `driver.page_source` will give u the html code of the page, which u can further parse to get the data that u want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've loaded Selenium and installed webdriver Chrome. Now to read up on them both to see how they work. :)

Comment: Okay...Happy learning! BTW, pls let me know whether my code works after u try it out.

Comment: Hi Sushil, your code worked great and I extracted the html code before stripping out the text. It seems now the most prudent way to obtain the complete dataset of each round for all 100+players is to access each player individually (/leaderboard/team/9?roundNo=3&holeNo=11), select 'Shots' and then select each hole 1-18 individually. Presumably this is only a few extra lines of code and then put it all in a for loop? I've learned plenty in the last couple of days and seemingly always want to run before I can walk so I appreciate you pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I've managed to extract some small snippets myself using your template and pulled them into a panda dataframe so I can see what's possible. I can visualise the finished goal, just need to work out the necessary code now?!